# Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds on while loop pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[[Here is how my last data from my dataframe and at the end errors which are occuring]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKRHJ.png) I am printing out data within a specific range. For example, `now + 200 sec`, so here I am printing data within 200 seconds from now.

I tried a while loop, that is printing data within the time date+200 seconds. However at the end if there is data's time less than date+200 seconds
, it is raising an error  "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

```
file = pd.read_hdf('KazSTSAT5.h5', mode = 'r', index_col = 'time')

df = pd.DataFrame (file)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
initial_size = df.size

while True:
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', -1)
    #first date in dataframe
    first_datetime = df.iloc[1, 1]
    #date range 200 sec
    i = pd.date_range(first_datetime, periods=200, freq='S')
    b = df.loc[(df.time >= i[0]) & (df.time <= i[-1])]

    c = pd.concat([df, b, b]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
    size = c.size
    initial_size = size
    df = c
```

How to get results if time less than date+200 seconds? So it just has to save what in dataleft.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how `df` looks like?

Comment: Hi, according to your variable name, you want to set the first entry in `first_datetime = df.iloc[1, 1]` but you actually use the second row (`.loc[0, 1]` would be the second column of the first row). Was that by intention?

Comment: What do you intend to do with `pd.concat([df, b, b]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`? I guess the second `b` you concatenate will be entirely removed later due to the `drop_duplicates`, or did I miss something?

Comment: @Aryerez I uploaded

Comment: @jottbe So as I understood it takes requested data from an original dateframe, and creates new one without requested data

Comment: That's a really odd logic. I think it deletes all rows. In each iteration it deletes the rows of a 200ms slot by creating duplicates and then removing them again along with the original records they were duplicated from. But the loop never exits, so II guess in the end you always will get an error. Can you please tell more, what you really want to do?

Comment: @jottbe I am trying to extract data within 200 seconds and create new vector. So if there is a data for 2000 seconds, there should be 10 vectors each containing data with 200 seconds. For example, 1 vector data includes time+ 200 seconds, then 2 vector data time+ 200+200, and so on. Note that: Time is taking from 'time' column

Comment: So you are trying to do something like an aggregation based on 200 second-intervals, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.loc[df.loc[:,'time'] < date+200,:]
```

Comment: There should be time period

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know, when you reach the point where the `min`- and `max`-time are less than 200 seconds apart, you can do that as follows:

Identify the point in time when your loop has to terminate:

```
mn= df2['time'].min()
mx= df2['time'].max()

td= mx-mn
if td.seconds < 200:
    # do something usefull here to process the rest of data
    break  # exit the loop
```

Alternative approach, if you want to aggregate the data

But I think, what you actually do is some kind of aggregation and if so, there might be a more efficient way to process your data.

To approach this, you could create a date range with 200 second slots and merge it with `merge_asof` to be able to group it later.

So the basic idea would be as follows:

```
# create a date range and convert it to a series
# just make sure, you set the end properly
interval_series= interval_series= pd.date_range(start='2019-09-10 02:18:23', end='2030-08-01 00:00:00', freq='200S').to_series()
interval_series.name= 'interval_time'

# now align that index to your data
# to use the following, you have to make sure,
# your time column is of type datetime64
index_date_df= pd.merge_asof(df[['time']], interval_series, left_on='time', right_index=True)

# now you can use the assigned intrval time,
# which is from the date_range, to group
# your dataframe
# the following example would just take the 
# first row within each 200s slot
index_date_df['interval_time']
df.groupby(index_date_df['interval_time']).agg('first').reset_index(drop=True)
```

That outputs:

```
Out[78]: 
   country                time
0      USA 2019-09-10 02:18:23
1       MX 2019-09-10 02:24:48
2      USA 2019-09-10 02:25:34
3      USA 2019-09-10 02:29:07
4      USA 2019-09-10 02:32:21
5       MX 2019-09-10 02:38:36
6       MX 2019-09-10 02:43:34
7      USA 2019-09-10 02:47:09
8      USA 2019-09-10 02:48:48
9      USA 2019-09-10 02:55:56
10     USA 2019-09-10 03:01:33
11      MX 2019-09-10 03:02:09
12     USA 2019-09-10 03:05:42
13      MX 2019-09-10 03:09:42
14      MX 2019-09-10 03:12:39
```

From the following testdata:

```
import io
raw=\
"""   country                time
0      USA 2019-09-10 02:18:23
1      USA 2019-09-10 02:19:53
2       MX 2019-09-10 02:24:48
3      USA 2019-09-10 02:25:34
4      USA 2019-09-10 02:29:07
5       MX 2019-09-10 02:29:43
6      USA 2019-09-10 02:32:21
7      USA 2019-09-10 02:34:58
8       MX 2019-09-10 02:38:36
9       MX 2019-09-10 02:39:49
10      MX 2019-09-10 02:43:34
11      MX 2019-09-10 02:44:51
12     USA 2019-09-10 02:47:09
13     USA 2019-09-10 02:48:11
14     USA 2019-09-10 02:48:48
15      MX 2019-09-10 02:51:19
16     USA 2019-09-10 02:55:56
17     USA 2019-09-10 02:58:17
18     USA 2019-09-10 03:01:33
19      MX 2019-09-10 03:02:09
20     USA 2019-09-10 03:05:42
21     USA 2019-09-10 03:08:00
22      MX 2019-09-10 03:09:42
23      MX 2019-09-10 03:12:39"""

df2= pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(raw), widths=[3, 8, 20])
df2['time']= df2['time'].astype('datetime64')
```